# VS2008 Setup Project - Overwrite Newer Version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

VS2008 setup projects provide the option to halt installation if a newer version is detected by setting "DetectNewerInstalledVersion". Is there a way to remove a newer version if it exists ie similar to "RemovePreviousVersions" options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have wished for this too, but only in the context of triaging inconsistincies between versions and testing installers as I write them!

Not meaning to be smart, but how would this help the user - it merely exposes them to risk of undoing a good installation.

See also [.NET Install Package Sometimes Not Completely Removing Previous Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290011/net-install-package-sometimes-not-completely-removing-previous-versions)

As 2008 doesnt do a naive uninstall + install, the install step would need to be able to handle both upgrade and downgrade scenarios.

So 1) beause 2008 doesnt work that way, 2) because its not a normal use case